# Microsoft Excel unable to access files on Disk

Tags: excel

I have created an Excel file (as a sort of an index to files on my disk) in which I have inserted links pointing to various text, image and pdf files on my hard disk on Macbook Pro. I have edited security preferences to allow Excel full access to my disk as well as folders. Even then, when I click on a link in any of the cells in the sheet, Excel is unable to open any of the files. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Any specific errors you might have seen?

Comment: It asks for access to the file I am trying to open, but I am unable to click on the file (it is greyed out) and grant access to Excel to the file. End of Story!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As it happens, I was playing around with the Security and Privacy settings an hour ago and managed to solve the problem. So the problem can be treated a closed. Thank you!